# debug assertion failed

Tags: c++, winforms

I keep getting a debug assertion failed error and I can't figure out why. I get the error when this code is ran:

```
     private: System::Void txtMessage_KeyDown(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) {
         if(e->KeyCode == Keys::Enter && txtMessage->Text != ""){

             char* MESSAGE = new char[txtMessage->Text->Length];
             ZeroMemory(MESSAGE, sizeof(MESSAGE));

             string strMESSAGE = "";

             MarshalString(txtMessage->Text, strMESSAGE);
             memcpy(MESSAGE, strMESSAGE.c_str(), sizeof(strMESSAGE));

             if (send(sConnect, MESSAGE, 256, NULL) != SOCKET_ERROR){
                 txtMessage->Clear();
             }
         }
     }
```

Sometimes the error doesn't occur until after I use that code multiple times and sometimes I get it the first time I use it. I really don't know why I am getting this and, I can't figure out how to fix it. So if anyone can help I would appreciate it.

The error I keep getting during that code is:
[image]

Comment: Every line of code inside the if statement has a bug.  Do consider using System::Net::Socket so you don't have to fall back to this mix of C and C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
char* MESSAGE = new char[txtMessage->Text->Length];
ZeroMemory(MESSAGE, sizeof(MESSAGE));
```

as it will only zeroise `sizeof(char*)` bytes instead of intended `Length`.

The allocation for `MESSAGE` is also based on `txtMessage` but is written to from `strMessage`. It may be the case that the lengths of these string objects are not equal, possibly resulting in allocating insufficient memory.

The use of `memcpy()` is also incorrect:

```
memcpy(MESSAGE, strMESSAGE.c_str(), sizeof(strMESSAGE));
```

as `sizeof(strMESSAGE)` is not the number of characters in `strMESSAGE`. Use `length()` instead.

The call to `send()` will also be attempting to access `256` characters from `MESSAGE` which may be greater than that allocated for `MESSAGE` resulting accessing memory it should not.

I am unsure why the call `send()` is not simply:

```
if (send(sConnect,strMESSAGE.c_str(),strMESSAGE.length(), NULL) != SOCKET_ERROR){
```

avoiding any dynamic memory allocation or copying.

*Just to note I am unfamiliar with `MarshalString()` so cannot comment on its use.*